# Internal Network Web Server - Host Name

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-7, hostname

I have a web server in our network that I would like to access with a host name like stage.blabla.com.

What are the general steps I need to take to set this up? I have no experience as a sysadmin. I am asking this out of curiosity.

My sites are hosted in IIS 7 and Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're not the sysadmin, I assume you cannot manage your intranet's DNS.  Just ask your sysadmin to add an A (or maybe CNAME) record for your web server's IP.

Comment: We are a small company that doesn't really have a sysadmin. When we need something like this done, we have a partner that we usually go to. I'm asking because I would like to know the general idea of how to do it. What do you use to manage the DNS?

Comment: @Dismissile: You manage DNS with what ever tools your DNS server requires.  Do you know if you run your own DNS? Or is it hosted?  Should you go mucking about in your DNS config without understanding the ramifications of breaking something, you could cause yourself more problems.  Regardless, go ask your partner to add a DNS A/CNAME record for this server -- they should know what you need configured.

Comment: Ok. Lets say I have added a DNS record that says stage.foobar.com points to my web server. Is there anything that I need to do in IIS to tie this together? I want to access it like: http://stage.foobar.com

Comment: @Dismissile: You shouldn't need to tweak IIS... Unless you're trying run multiple sites on a single IIS server. If that is the case you'll need to configure [host headers](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;324287) in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

JScott's answer is the best way to do it.  If you can't get the records inserted into DNS for some reason, you could always use your local HOSTS file instead.  That's a means of manually defining a local IP-to-DomainName mapping.  It's located in `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\HOSTS` on most Windows boxes.

The proper method using DNS is the better way in every shape and form.  I'm just tossing this out there, as it would technically work.  And it's useful knowledge to have.

Comment: You may want to mention that modifying the hosts file will only work for the computer which has the edited file.  Changes to the hosts file do not "propagate" to other computers on the network.

Comment: I'm familiar with modifying the hosts file. How would you go about modifying the DNS records? Is there a tool sysadmins use?

Comment: No, it depends on how you are getting your DNS. Do you host your own DNS server, @Dismissile? Or do you use one upstream at your Internet provider? Otherwise, if you're a small business, you would probably be better off doing the hosts file method OR getting someone to come in and set up a small proxying DNS server in your network.